# OLS regressions and Type I error

Tags: least-squares, lasso

Suppose I run an OLS regression with 300 variables, and 45 are significant at the 10% level. When writing up my results, should I note that the observed statistical significance is likely to be spurious (i.e. Type I error) for around 30 of those variables?

Will the answer to the above question change if the OLS I did was actually a post-Lasso OLS? (That is, in order to avoid high-dimensionality problems, let's say I did Lasso on half the dataset. Then *using the other half of the dataset*, I ran an OLS regression with *only* the coefficients that were non-zero from the Lasso analysis.)

Comment: do you mean spurious for 45 of those variables? Or where does the 30 come from?

Comment: @rannoudanames because the false-positive error rate of 10% tells us that, for each of the 300 comparisons, we expect 0.1*300=30 of them to be false positives.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** - You can say that if there is actually no true relationship between any of the explanatory variables and the response variable, then you would expect approximately 30 of them to show up as significant due to Type I error.  Bear in mind that this can only be a rough statement, since the p-values for tests on variables in a regression are not independent.